# Document AI - Improving batch process time for a single document?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, cloud-document-ai

I'm working on a GCP [Document AI](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai) project. First, let me say this - the OCR works fine :-). I'm curios to know about possibilities of improvement if possible.

**What happens now**

I have a python module written, which will get the OCR done for a tiff file which is uploaded via a portal or collected by an agent in the system. The module is written in a way to avoid local usage of original file content, as the file is readily available in a cloud bucket. But, the price I have to pay is to use the `batch_process_documents()` API instead of `process_document()`.

**An observation**

This is an obvious one, as the document if submitted via inline API gets OCR back in less than 5 seconds most time. But, the batch (with a single document :-|) takes more than 45 seconds almost every time. Sometimes it goes beyond a minute or more.

---

I'm searching for a solution, to reduce the OCR call time. The inline API does not support gcs uris as much as I'm aware, so either I need to download the content, upload it back via inline api and then do an OCR - or I need to live with the performance reduction.

Is there any one who has handled a similar case ? Or if there are any ways to tackle this without using batch api or downloading the content ? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

As per your requirement, since your concern is  related to the latency when comparing the response time between the **process** and **batchProcess** method calls for the Document API, using a single document with results of 5 and 45 seconds respectively.

- The [process_documents()](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1beta2/projects.locations.documents/process) method has limits on the number of pages and file size that can be sent and it only allows for one document file per API call.
- The [batch_process_documents()](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1beta2/projects.locations.documents/batchProcess) method allows asynchronous processing of larger files and batch processing of multiple files.

Single requests are oriented to smaller amounts of data that usually takes a very small amount of time to process but may have low performance when dealing with a big amount of data, on the other hand batch requests are oriented to handle bigger amounts of data which would have better performance over the single request but may have lower performance when processing a small amount of data.

Regarding your concerns about the latency on these two method calls, looking into the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/data-usage),I am able to find that for the single request or **synchronous ("online") operations ( i.e immediate response)** the document data is processed in memory and not persisted to disk. Following this in **asynchronous offline batch operations** the documents are processed in disk, due that the file could be significatively bigger that could not fit in memory. That's why the asynchronous operations take around 10x time vs the synchronous operations.

Each of these method calls  has a particular use case, in this case the choice of which one to use would rely on the trade off that's better for you. If the time response is critical and you would like to have the response as soon as possible, you could split the files to fit the size  and make the requests as synchronous operations, keeping in mind the [quotas](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/processors-list#general_processors) and limitations of the API.

This issue has been raised in this [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/221007215). We cannot provide an ETA at this moment but you can follow the progress in the issue tracker and you can ‘STAR’ the issue to receive automatic updates and give it traction by referring to this [Link](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/subscribe#starring_an_issue).

Comment: I'm aware of the use case difference in these calls. I agree with you async ops with disk persistence is the key for the latency. But It would have been a good addition for the online process to support a bucket resource URI instead of file content on wire. I suppose its more of a feature request rather than a bug report :-). But moving the file content from bucket to app, app to docai, and ocr back to bucket may not be an option I want to try. Hope Google brings up something !

Comment: To read from GCS files, you need to read from the GCS client library in your python code. could you refer to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#prereq-code-samples) and this [code sample](https://github.com/googleapis/python-storage/blob/HEAD/samples/snippets/storage_download_into_memory.py) which shows you how to download objects into memory from your buckets in Cloud Storage. You need to add the above logic to the python document AI code in order to read GCS files.

Comment: :-) I think probably I was not clear in my comment. I do not want to transfer files from GCS to my app. I was just making an inquiry, if there is a way to specify gcs uri in the online request. I think that is not possible any way.

Comment: Hi, @Kris I have created a feature request for the same and updated the answer with the feature request link.

Comment: that is cool! Thanks a lot. Will keep an eye on that!

Comment: The issue is still open with Google issue tracker with many more +1s. Any chance this will be available soon ? :-)

Answer (score 0):

Since this was originally posted, the Document AI API added a feature to specify a `field_mask` in the processing request, which limits the fields returned in the Document object output. This can reduce the latency in some requests since the response will be a smaller size.

https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/send-request#online-processor