# How to process a single GCS-stored file on Document AI with the Python client?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, cloud-document-ai

I have been testing out the Google Document AI Python client,
but I couldn't get the [`process_document()`](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/documentai/latest/google.cloud.documentai_v1.services.document_processor_service.DocumentProcessorServiceClient#google_cloud_documentai_v1_services_document_processor_service_DocumentProcessorServiceClient_process_document)
function working when trying to process *one single document* stored on Google Cloud Storage.

What I currently have:

- A working [quick start](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/process-documents-client-libraries#using_the_client_library) example, which processes a single *locally stored* document
- A working [Batch Processing](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/send-request#batch-process) example, which processes *multiple* GCS stored documents

Other options I've tried:

- I have tried modifying the quick start example, but have been unable to get it to work for GCS stored files *(more details below)*
- I can use the batch processing code for a single file. However, using batch processing appears to significantly slow down the processing speed compared to uploading local files
- Another option I have considered is downloading my GCS-based file and re-uploading, but it seems to be both a waste of bandwidth and inelegant

Which brings me to the question, how do you process a single GCS-stored file with the Python client?

---

I have tried modifying the quick start example by replacing the class
[`RawDocument`](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/documentai/latest/google.cloud.documentai_v1.types.RawDocument)
with other classes that takes in GCS URI as input, but it didn't work:

- The class [`GcsDocument`](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/documentai/latest/google.cloud.documentai_v1.types.GcsDocument)
  isn't accepted by [`ProcessRequest`](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/documentai/latest/google.cloud.documentai_v1.types.ProcessRequest)
  to begin with.
  Trying to pass `GcsDocument` to either the `raw_document` or `inline_document` attribute anyway will raise the error:
  `TypeError: Message must be initialized with a dict: google.cloud.documentai.v1.ProcessRequest`
- The class [`Document`](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/documentai/latest/google.cloud.documentai_v1.types.Document)
  appears to be usable with `ProcessRequest(inline_document=Document())`.
  However, even following the example provided by
  [`process_document()`](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/documentai/latest/google.cloud.documentai_v1.services.document_processor_service.DocumentProcessorServiceClient#google_cloud_documentai_v1_services_document_processor_service_DocumentProcessorServiceClient_process_document)
  will then raise the error:
  `400 Only content payload is supported for Sync Process.`

Here is a code snippet that will raise this error:

```py
from google.api_core.client_options import ClientOptions
from google.cloud import documentai

opts = ClientOptions(api_endpoint=f"us-documentai.googleapis.com")
client = documentai.DocumentProcessorServiceClient(client_options=opts)
name = client.processor_path("my_project_id", "us", "my_processor_id")

gcs_document = documentai.Document(
    uri = "gs://my_image.jpeg",
    mime_type = "image/jpeg"
)
request = documentai.ProcessRequest(
    name = name,
    inline_document = gcs_document
)

# 400 Only content payload is supported for Sync Process.
result = client.process_document(request=request)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>You cannot use Online Processing `process_document()` for files in Google Cloud Storage without downloading them locally.</strike>

**Update:** Online Processing functionality has been updated to allow processing of a single file in Google Cloud storage. You can add a GCS document link using the `gcs_document` parameter in the [processing request](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.processors/process#request-body)

You can use Batch Processing `batch_process_documents()` to process a single document from Google Cloud Storage. It functions exactly the same as processing multiple documents with batch processing, but you just input a single document instead of a prefix or multiple documents. The input and output are both in Google Cloud Storage, and the processing is asynchronous.

The Python code sample in [Send a processing request > Batch processing](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/send-request#async-processor) shows exactly what you are looking for. Look for `#######`

```py
import re
from typing import Optional

from google.api_core.client_options import ClientOptions
from google.api_core.exceptions import InternalServerError
from google.api_core.exceptions import RetryError
from google.cloud import documentai  # type: ignore
from google.cloud import storage

# TODO(developer): Uncomment these variables before running the sample.
# project_id = "YOUR_PROJECT_ID"
# location = "YOUR_PROCESSOR_LOCATION" # Format is "us" or "eu"
# processor_id = "YOUR_PROCESSOR_ID" # Create processor before running sample
# gcs_output_uri = "YOUR_OUTPUT_URI" # Must end with a trailing slash `/`. Format: gs://bucket/directory/subdirectory/
# processor_version_id = "YOUR_PROCESSOR_VERSION_ID" # Optional. Example: pretrained-ocr-v1.0-2020-09-23

# TODO(developer): You must specify either `gcs_input_uri` and `mime_type` or `gcs_input_prefix`
# gcs_input_uri = "YOUR_INPUT_URI" # Format: gs://bucket/directory/file.pdf
# input_mime_type = "application/pdf"
# gcs_input_prefix = "YOUR_INPUT_URI_PREFIX" # Format: gs://bucket/directory/
# field_mask = "text,entities,pages.pageNumber"  # Optional. The fields to return in the Document object.


def batch_process_documents(
    project_id: str,
    location: str,
    processor_id: str,
    gcs_output_uri: str,
    processor_version_id: Optional[str] = None,
    gcs_input_uri: Optional[str] = None,
    input_mime_type: Optional[str] = None,
    gcs_input_prefix: Optional[str] = None,
    field_mask: Optional[str] = None,
    timeout: int = 400,
) -> None:
    # You must set the `api_endpoint` if you use a location other than "us".
    opts = ClientOptions(api_endpoint=f"{location}-documentai.googleapis.com")

    client = documentai.DocumentProcessorServiceClient(client_options=opts)

    if gcs_input_uri:
        # Specify specific GCS URIs to process individual documents
        gcs_document = documentai.GcsDocument(
            gcs_uri=gcs_input_uri, mime_type=input_mime_type
        )
        ##############
        # This line is where the single document is being added
        ##############
        gcs_documents = documentai.GcsDocuments(documents=[gcs_document])
        input_config = documentai.BatchDocumentsInputConfig(gcs_documents=gcs_documents)
    else:
        # Specify a GCS URI Prefix to process an entire directory
        gcs_prefix = documentai.GcsPrefix(gcs_uri_prefix=gcs_input_prefix)
        input_config = documentai.BatchDocumentsInputConfig(gcs_prefix=gcs_prefix)

    # Cloud Storage URI for the Output Directory
    gcs_output_config = documentai.DocumentOutputConfig.GcsOutputConfig(
        gcs_uri=gcs_output_uri, field_mask=field_mask
    )

    # Where to write results
    output_config = documentai.DocumentOutputConfig(gcs_output_config=gcs_output_config)

    if processor_version_id:
        # The full resource name of the processor version, e.g.:
        # projects/{project_id}/locations/{location}/processors/{processor_id}/processorVersions/{processor_version_id}
        name = client.processor_version_path(
            project_id, location, processor_id, processor_version_id
        )
    else:
        # The full resource name of the processor, e.g.:
        # projects/{project_id}/locations/{location}/processors/{processor_id}
        name = client.processor_path(project_id, location, processor_id)

    request = documentai.BatchProcessRequest(
        name=name,
        input_documents=input_config,
        document_output_config=output_config,
    )

    # BatchProcess returns a Long Running Operation (LRO)
    operation = client.batch_process_documents(request)

    # Continually polls the operation until it is complete.
    # This could take some time for larger files
    # Format: projects/{project_id}/locations/{location}/operations/{operation_id}
    try:
        print(f"Waiting for operation {operation.operation.name} to complete...")
        operation.result(timeout=timeout)
    # Catch exception when operation doesn't finish before timeout
    except (RetryError, InternalServerError) as e:
        print(e.message)

    # NOTE: Can also use callbacks for asynchronous processing
    #
    # def my_callback(future):
    #   result = future.result()
    #
    # operation.add_done_callback(my_callback)

    # Once the operation is complete,
    # get output document information from operation metadata
    metadata = documentai.BatchProcessMetadata(operation.metadata)

    if metadata.state != documentai.BatchProcessMetadata.State.SUCCEEDED:
        raise ValueError(f"Batch Process Failed: {metadata.state_message}")

    storage_client = storage.Client()

    print("Output files:")
    # One process per Input Document
    for process in list(metadata.individual_process_statuses):
        # output_gcs_destination format: gs://BUCKET/PREFIX/OPERATION_NUMBER/INPUT_FILE_NUMBER/
        # The Cloud Storage API requires the bucket name and URI prefix separately
        matches = re.match(r"gs://(.*?)/(.*)", process.output_gcs_destination)
        if not matches:
            print(
                "Could not parse output GCS destination:",
                process.output_gcs_destination,
            )
            continue

        output_bucket, output_prefix = matches.groups()

        # Get List of Document Objects from the Output Bucket
        output_blobs = storage_client.list_blobs(output_bucket, prefix=output_prefix)

        # Document AI may output multiple JSON files per source file
        for blob in output_blobs:
            # Document AI should only output JSON files to GCS
            if blob.content_type != "application/json":
                print(
                    f"Skipping non-supported file: {blob.name} - Mimetype: {blob.content_type}"
                )
                continue

            # Download JSON File as bytes object and convert to Document Object
            print(f"Fetching {blob.name}")
            document = documentai.Document.from_json(
                blob.download_as_bytes(), ignore_unknown_fields=True
            )

            # For a full list of Document object attributes, please reference this page:
            # https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/documentai/latest/google.cloud.documentai_v1.types.Document

            # Read the text recognition output from the processor
            print("The document contains the following text:")
            print(document.text)
```

Comment: Can "gcs_document" be a file stored in Firebase Storage as opposed to Cloud Storage? I have swapped "raw_document" with "gcs_document" and added the file location to it but it still did not work, getting an error (unsupported file format)? I am using Firebase Storage. I wonder if that is the issue.

Comment: No, it must be in Google Cloud Storage (GCS)

Comment: Does Document AI API work with Firebase Storage if Batch processing is used?

Comment: No it does not, the documents must be in Google Cloud Storage.

Answer (score 3):

For your requirement, you can consider the below code as a workaround:

```
from google.cloud import storage
import base64
from google.api_core.client_options import ClientOptions
from google.cloud import documentai
PROJECT_ID = "my-project-id"
LOCATION = "us"  
PROCESSOR_ID = "my-processor-id"  
MIME_TYPE = "image/jpeg"
bucket_name = "my-bucket-name"
file_name = "my-file-name.jpeg"

def gcs_file_to_base64():
    client = storage.Client()
    bucket = client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(file_name)
    local_path = f"{file_name}"
    blob.download_to_filename(local_path)
    with open(local_path, "rb") as file:
        encoded_string = base64.b64encode(file.read()).decode("utf-8")
    return encoded_string

docai_client = documentai.DocumentProcessorServiceClient(
    client_options=ClientOptions(api_endpoint=f"{LOCATION}-documentai.googleapis.com")
)

RESOURCE_NAME = docai_client.processor_path(PROJECT_ID, LOCATION, PROCESSOR_ID)
raw_document = documentai.RawDocument(content=gcs_file_to_base64(), mime_type=MIME_TYPE)
request = documentai.ProcessRequest(name=RESOURCE_NAME, raw_document=raw_document)
result = docai_client.process_document(request=request)
document_object = result.document
print("\n Document processing complete.\n")
print(f"Text: {document_object.text}")
```

In the above code, I first downloaded the gcs file and converted it into base64 encoded string. Then I gave this encoded string as input for the documentation ai. You can follow [this](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/send-request#batch-process) **batch processing** example code to use the GCS URI directly. For more information, please refer to these [link1](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/send-request#online-process) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74246490/google-document-ai-with-gs-uri-results-in-3-invalid-argument-document-bytes).

For online processing document requests through Document AI, there is no option to load data from GCS. It only supports loading data from the local path.However,there is a feature [request filed](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/221007215) for the same.You can vote for this feature by clicking the "+1" and "STAR" mark to receive updates on it or you can also create a feature request thread in [Google’s Public Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).

Comment: Thanks for the answer; I have considered this approach, but it uses too much bandwidth for the use case I am working on. So an approach that keeps the files on GCS would be preferrable.

Comment: Hi @mimocha, I have updated my answer, consider accepting and upvoting if it addresses your question. Take a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71204952/document-ai-improving-batch-process-time-for-a-single-document) also.